# C# Change HTTP request headers

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make my own proxy server, but because broxy you cant get user real ip because it returns proxy IP. I have tried about one hour to add header that contains user real IP. Its basic proxy that send data to real server and return data back to user.

Code where I try edit headers:

```
HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(packet);
content.Headers.Add("USER_IP", this.GetIP());

byte[] finalData = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(finalData));
```

When it prints result to console... Its same as it was before, and same lenght :s

Comment: You should try cloning the packet.  If you are proxy you are making a second request and you should be able to edit that request, instead of editing the request from the client

Comment: @mageos That code is from proxy, I clone it already with new ByteArrayContent(packet); and then try add that header and send it to real server.

Comment: If I remember correctly ReadAsByteArrayAsync, ReadAsStringAsync ecc will read only the actual content (in fact generally is the only information you need). To retrieve the Headers, in your example case, you need to read them from the Headers property. Have you tried to actually send the data and see what arrives on the other end?

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Yeah my problem is that it dont return those my headers, and yes I have tried return that header using PHP

Comment: It actually works for me, note that in the respose you don't have to use ReadAsByteArrayAsync but you have to read the headers of it.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini How I can send the whole request with all data if i read only headers?

Comment: When you receive data you don't receive directly the stream in c#, you receive an object (for example if you're using HttpClient you receive a HttpResponseMessage) that object contains both the headers and the content that you can read as a stream. So the receiver can read both the content and the headers

Comment: @FabioMarcolini I'm using sockets. What I receive is byte[] :P